# JOIN statement equivalence in book appears incorrect?

Tags: mysql, sql

Just after Figure 9-9 (in chapter 9) of SQL Queries for Mere Mortals 4th edition, the following two queries are presented as being equivalent solutions, yet they seem quite obviously not equivalent.

The problem statement is

```
“I need all the recipe types, and then the matching recipe names, preparation instructions,
ingredient names, ingredient step numbers, ingredient quantities, and ingredient measurements
from my recipes database, sorted in recipe title and step number sequence.”
```

Query 1:

```sql
SELECT 
    Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassDescription, 
    Recipes.RecipeTitle, 
    Recipes.Preparation,
    Ingredients.IngredientName, 
    Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeSeqNo, Recipe_Ingredients.Amount,
    Measurements.MeasurementDescription
FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                Recipe_Classes 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN Recipes
                ON Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassID = Recipes.RecipeClassID
            )
            INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredients
            ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
        )
        INNER JOIN Ingredients
        ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
    )
    INNER JOIN Measurements
    ON Measurements.MeasureAmountID = Recipe_Ingredients.MeasureAmountID
ORDER BY RecipeTitle, RecipeSeqNo
```

Query 2:

```sql
SELECT 
    Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassDescription, 
    Recipes.RecipeTitle, Recipes.Preparation,
    Ingredients.IngredientName, 
    Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeSeqNo, 
    Recipe_Ingredients.Amount,
    Measurements.MeasurementDescription
FROM 
    Recipe_Classes 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        (
            (
                Recipes INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredients
                ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
            )
            INNER JOIN Ingredients
            ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
        )
        INNER JOIN Measurements
        ON Measurements.MeasureAmountID = Recipe_Ingredients.MeasureAmountID
    )
    ON Recipe_Classes.RecipeClassID = Recipes.RecipeClassID
ORDER BY RecipeTitle, RecipeSeqNo
```

After giving Query 1, the author appears to say Query 2 is equivalent to it, as he writes

```
Joining more than two tables in an alternate sequence

To solve the request I just showed you using five tables, I could have also stated the SQL as follows:
```

Query 1 and Query 2 look non-equivalent.  If you have recipe types with no recipes (which the book states as part of the problem), Query 1 would not return those, as the INNER JOINs are parsed after the LEFT OUTER JOIN, destroying those rows.

Therefore, Query 1 is incorrect.

Query 2 would actually return all the recipe classes, with NULL column values for those recipe classes that don't have any matching recipes, so it appears to be the correct solution, if we make the assumption that the database is complete so that we don't lose some recipes along the way using the inner joins.

What am I not understanding about how joins work?  I can't see how these are equivalent.

Edit - formatted the queries for easier reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries are equivalent, but not for the reason given.  The condition:

```
ON Recipes.RecipeID = Recipe_Ingredients.RecipeID
```

turns the first query into a series of `INNER JOIN`s.

The condition:

```
ON Ingredients.IngredientID = Recipe_Ingredients.IngredientID
```

turns the second query into a series of `INNER JOIN`s.

When all the joins are `INNER JOIN`s, the ordering doesn't matter.

The format of the query is awful -- the author isn't using table aliases.  Having experience in this area, I know that I had to work hard to get queries to "print" nicely in books and removing long table aliases definitely helps.

Comment: Is the last join parsed in the 2nd query not the LEFT JOIN between Recipe_Classes and the result of that series of INNER JOINs?

If it all collapsed into a series of INNER JOINs, how would we be able to include the Recipe_Classes for which no Recipes are a member of?

Comment: Also, I just edited the query to be more readable, gave it nested indentation levels.

Comment: @0xN0 . . . Those queries do not include such classes.  Period.  The queries are wrong for that purpose. All joins need to be changed to `LEFT JOIN`s, but still, this is a published book so the query is wrong.

Comment: Ah I see.  Yea the queries seemed quite odd to me.  Thanks!